# Spacy Matcher isn't always matching

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, spacy-3

I can't figure out why the matcher isn't working. This works:

```
test = ["14k"]

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

matcher.add("test", [[{"NORM": "14k"}]])

docs = []
for doc in nlp.pipe(test):
    matches = matcher(doc)
    print(matches)
```

but if I change 14k to 14K in both my matcher and text, the matcher finds nothing.  Why? I just want to understand the difference and why this doesn't work and how I could go about troubleshooting this myself in the future.  I've looked at the docs:

https://spacy.io/api/matcher

and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.  I changed "NORM" to ORTH and TEXT and it still hasn't found it. Thank you for any help.

**EDIT**
OK, so I did:

```
for ent in doc:
   print(ent)
```

and for the lowercase version, Spacy was catorgizing it all as one ent, but when I uppercased the K, Spacy says it two different ents. With this knowledge I did, `matcher.add("test", [[{"ORTH": "14"}, {"ORTH":"K"}]])` and it worked.

I still want to know why.  Why does Spacy think 14k is one "word" but 14K is two "words"?

Comment: Maybe all you need is `{"LOWER": "14k"}`?

Comment: (Yay, pressing enter sends this response instead of adding a new line lol)

`matcher.add("test", [[{"LOWER": "14k"}]])` or `matcher.add("test", [[{"LOWER": "14K"}]])` does not return a match against `test = ["14K"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may be running into issues with differences in tokenization for this kind of sequence. In particular note that things that look like temperatures (so number + [FCK]) may get special treatment. This may seem odd but it usually results in better compatibility with existing corpora.

You can find out why an input is tokenized a particular way using `tokenizer.explain()` like so:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
print(nlp.tokenizer.explain("14K"))
print("...")
print(nlp.tokenizer.explain("14k"))
```

That gives the output:

```
[('TOKEN', '14'), ('SUFFIX', 'K')]
...
[('TOKEN', '14k')]
```

You can read more about this at the [`tokenizer.explain` docs](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features/#tokenizer-debug).

Comment: I noticed this yesterday when I used [displaCy](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy-ent?text=14K&model=en_core_web_sm) to visualize my data.  14k isn't given a label, but 14K is.  Well, the 14 is tagged as a cardinal and the K is left untagged. Using this visualizer [displaCy](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=14K&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=0&cph=0) and 14K, the 14 is called a num, and the K is a noun and 14k is just a now.  So I can see how Spacy is tokenizing items.

Comment: So to continue to help my understanding of spaCy, and the spaCy Order of Operations (OOO), it runs the tokenizer before looking for matches? I'm using [this](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines) for my theory on the OOO.

Comment: Rereading the documentation, you notice things you glanced over before.  Like this [**Important Note**](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) on rule based matching:
"When writing patterns, keep in mind that each dictionary represents one token. If spaCy’s tokenization doesn’t match the tokens defined in a pattern, the pattern is not going to produce any results. When developing complex patterns, make sure to check examples against spaCy’s tokenization:"


`doc = nlp("A complex-example,!")
print([token.text for token in doc])`